# Can we set arbitrary host name for AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have standard AWS EC2 instance. It has standard URL that was created by AWS automatically on EC2 creation:

```
ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I want to change host name for arbitrary value and it is not a public domain. And I want to access EC2 from Internet with that custom host name:

Instead: `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

I want at least: `foo.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Or even better: `foo.compute.amazonaws.com`

Is it possible in AWS?

Comment: Yes, you can set the hostname in the OS. No, you cannot change the external address AWS gives your instance. You can, however, buy your own domain name and point it towards your ec2 instance.

Comment: What do you mean by `the external address AWS gives your instance`? Is it what returns `dnsdomainname` command? And it returns `ap-southeast-2.compute.internal`

Comment: I mean that you can set the hostname to whatever you'd like, but it won't create a DNS record (and therefore will not be recognized outside of your local network)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change host name for arbitrary value and it is not a public
>   domain. And I want to access EC2 from Internet with that custom host
>   name ... EG foo.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> Is it possible in AWS?

No, it is not.  The external DNS hostname is the *authoritative* DNS name for that instance. That "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx" part is the IP # assigned for that instance. That hostname stays with that IP number/instance as long as it is assigned to it.

> Each instance that receives a public IP address is also given an
>   external DNS hostname; for example,
>   ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com. We resolve **an external DNS
>   hostname** to the public IP address of the instance outside the network
>   of the instance, and to the private IP address of the instance from
>   within the network of the instance.

Using DNS, of course you can alias that DNS hostname to any host in a custom domain. But you cannot modify the AWS given external DNS hostname.

See [Public IP Addresses and External DNS Hostnames](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I exactly meant *to alias* some arbitrary DNS host name to my EC2 instance. That is `foo.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is an alias to my initial `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. Not a public domain name that I can buy from registrars (like GoDaddy), but I only want to get rid of this part `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx` and set it, let's say, as `foo` , like `foo.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. Do I need to use their Route53 service or can I just modify `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname/` files? I tried to modify these files but it didn't make it.